# How to button click event on jQuery focus

Tags: jquery

I have two text boxes and a button.
 
I change the focus from one control to another whenever a keypress event is generated.

I want as soon the button get's focus it should  call the click event i.e., *onclick="btnIssue_Click1".*

How this should be done in jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#myButton").focus(function() {
    $(this).click();
});
```

It's worth noting that this is rather unusual behaviour, and is likely to confuse users.